# Display mongoDB data in a table in React in Chronological Order

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I have a table in react created from data stored in mongodb. Currently, my table of past orders are displayed with the most recent date at the bottom of the screen. I would like to have my data displayed in chronological order. I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to do this.
Thank you!

OrderHistoryScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { listOrderMine, detailsOrder } from '../actions/orderActions';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import { createReturn } from '../actions/returnActions';


export default function OrderHistoryScreen(props) {
  const order = useSelector((state) => state.order);
  const orderMineList = useSelector((state) => state.orderMineList);
  const { loading, error, orders } = orderMineList;
  console.log({ orders });
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listOrderMine());
    //dispatch(detailsOrder(orderId));
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Order History</h1>
      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
            <table className="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>DATE</th>
                  <th>TOTAL</th>
                  <th>PAID</th>
                  <th>DELIVERED</th>
                  <th>SHIPPED</th>
                  <th>ACTIONS</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {orders.map((order) => {
                  
                  return (
                    <tr key={order._id}>
                      <td>{order._id}</td>
                      <td>{order.createdAt.substring(0, 10)}</td>
                      <td>
                        <button
                          type="button"
                          className="small"
                          onClick={() => {
                            props.history.push(`/order/${order._id}`);
                          }}
                        >
                          Details
                  </button>
                      </td>

                    </tr>
                  )
                })}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

OrderAction.js

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import { CART_EMPTY } from '../constants/cartConstants';
import {
    ORDER_CREATE_FAIL,
    ORDER_CREATE_REQUEST,
    ORDER_CREATE_SUCCESS,
    ORDER_DETAILS_FAIL,
    ORDER_DETAILS_REQUEST,
    ORDER_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
    ORDER_MINE_LIST_REQUEST,
    ORDER_MINE_LIST_FAIL,
    ORDER_MINE_LIST_SUCCESS,
    ORDER_LIST_REQUEST,
    ORDER_LIST_SUCCESS,
    ORDER_LIST_FAIL,
    ORDER_DELETE_REQUEST,
    ORDER_DELETE_SUCCESS,
    ORDER_DELETE_FAIL,

} from '../constants/orderConstants';
import { BASE_URL } from '../constants/app.constants';

export const createOrder = (order) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: ORDER_CREATE_REQUEST, payload: order });
    try {
        const {
            userSignin: { userInfo },
        } = getState();
        const { data } = await Axios.post('/api/orders', order, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
            },
        });
        dispatch({ type: ORDER_CREATE_SUCCESS, payload: data.order });
        dispatch({ type: CART_EMPTY });
        localStorage.removeItem('cartItems');
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: ORDER_CREATE_FAIL,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message,
        });
    }
};
export const detailsOrder = (orderId) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: ORDER_DETAILS_REQUEST, payload: orderId });
    const {
        userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    try {
        const { data } = await Axios.get(`/api/orders/${orderId}`, {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
        });
        dispatch({ type: ORDER_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
        const message = error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message;
        dispatch({ type: ORDER_DETAILS_FAIL, payload: message });
    }
};

export const listOrderMine = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: ORDER_MINE_LIST_REQUEST });
    const {
        userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    try {
        const { data } = await Axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/orders/mine`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
            },
        });
        dispatch({ type: ORDER_MINE_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
        const message = error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message;
        dispatch({ type: ORDER_MINE_LIST_FAIL, payload: message });
    }
};
export const listOrders =
    ({ seller = '' }) =>
    async (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({ type: ORDER_LIST_REQUEST });
        const {
            userSignin: { userInfo },
        } = getState();
        try {
            const { data } = await Axios.get(`/api/orders?seller=${seller}`, {
                headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
            });
            console.log(data);
            dispatch({ type: ORDER_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
        } catch (error) {
            const message = error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message;
            dispatch({ type: ORDER_LIST_FAIL, payload: message });
        }
    };
export const deleteOrder = (orderId) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: ORDER_DELETE_REQUEST, payload: orderId });
    const {
        userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    try {
        const { data } = Axios.delete(`/api/orders/${orderId}`, {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
        });
        dispatch({ type: ORDER_DELETE_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
        const message = error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message;
        dispatch({ type: ORDER_DELETE_FAIL, payload: message });
    }
};
```

Comment: In general, you can apply sort on the data being queried from the database. MongoDB queries support _sort_ operations on any field, in a query.

Comment: @prasad_ Okay, I figured I needed a sort, so I have this                                              ```const sortedDate = data.sort((a, b) => {const dateA = (new Date(a.createdAt)).getTime(); const dateB = (new Date(b.createdAt)).getTime(); return dateB - dateA;})``` 
 The issue actually is more of where in my code I would place this? I had tried placing it after ```{orders.map((order) => {```, but that didn't work.